# Assign number 1-12 to another set of number when reached 12 start at 1 again for the next number and continue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Question:
Is there an Excel formula to make below possible in 1 cell without having to create table and do a lookup? Because the number set can go very far to like 10,000.

Assign a number 1-12 to another set of number, when it reached 12 go back to 1 again.

Result:
The result I'm looking for is, to plugin the number for example 109 and it return 10.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your target cell put formula

=MOD(X-100, 12) +1 where X is your input cell.

Comment: Thank you so much! I test it with a few sets of number, some work perfectly but some return 0 instead of 12, not sure why? I can't add picture here, will find the way to add an example.

Comment: Hi CeeCee I just corrected the answer to account for this, please try again.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you, but I can't seem to find the correction, where do I find it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The =MOD(X, 12) +1 make the number over by 1 (what should be 1 is 2 and so on, so I adjusted to below formula is it work like a charm)

=MOD(100-1, 12) +1

Thank you!!!

Comment: The answer should be available just above in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(MOD(ROWS(A$1:A1),12)=0,12,MOD(ROWS(A$1:A1),12))`
If MOD result is `0` it returns `12` otherwise it returns the MOD result.